# How to use SWRL rules on Protegé 4.3 using Pellet

Tags: protege, pellet, swrl

I've just started doing work on ontologies with Protegé and I'm trying to understand how to use SWRL rules. I'm afraid I don't get the concept or how to correctly treat them, as I'm not able to produce any output. I'll explain a bit more a simple case I created to test this:

I've created three individuals, called A, B and C. Each one with a test property, that has a boolean range. On the property assertions tab of each one I've initialized their values, so they are `test(A,true)`, `test(B,true)` and `test(C,true)`. To test how rules work, I created a rule like this: `test(A,true), test(B,true) -> test(C,false)`. The way I understand it is that, if A and B's test property is true, C's one would turn false. To do so, I start the reasoner (Pellet) but nothing happens. I mean, it says the reasoner is active and no "inconsistent ontology" messages appear, but C's test value doesn't change. I'm sure this must be a really simple confusion but I can't seem to find it anywhere nor check if the rule has been activated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inference doesnt work like that, you cannot retract `test(C, true)` if you've asserted it.  Your ontology probably includes both `test(C, true)` and `test(C, false)` which is completely legal unless you've specified otherwise; in which case *then* you'd see the inconsistency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, what would be the correct procedure for initializing the value of a property and then changing it inside a rule?

Comment: You cannot retract asserted information via a rule, it just does not work like that.  For your example, you should leave the value for `test` on `C` unspecified, and construct the rule such that it will always infer a value for it.  That way if you change the assertion for `A` or `B` the inferred value of `test` for `C` will change appropriately.

Comment: Okay, I guess data assertions work as I first thought... So, is there any way working with OWL and SWRL to "initialize" (understanding it as you would do in Java, for example) a property's value and change it to another value when a rule is activated?

Comment: Yes, by having the rule do it.

Comment: Hey again! I'm working again on this problem. To test this initialization problem I've created a test class called Test, an individual of that class called Indiv and a property called Prop, with Test domain and int range. After that, I created a rule like this: "Test(Indiv)->Prop(Indiv,5)". If I understood your explanation correctly, now Indiv should have a 5 on its Prop property, but I can't see anything happening (Probably that's another question, how can I see on Protegé the change the rule does?)

Comment: New questions should not be posted as comments.

Comment: Umm, OK, I guess, though it would be a little more helpful if, apart from correcting me you stated how to correctly ask this question, which is totally related to the problem at hand.